# Azure.Identity Throws Not implemented Exception on Platform Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, microsoft-graph-api, azure-sdk-.net

I'm trying to authenticate via graph api to AD with Azure.Identity UsernamePasswordCredential but whenever I initialise the credential ctor, it throws the following exception:

```
The method or operation is not implemented. at System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.GetSources ()
```

Stack trace:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Azure.Core.Pipeline.LoggingPolicy' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Azure.Core.Diagnostics.AzureCoreEventSource' threw an exception. ---> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
  at System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.GetSources () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.Diagnostics.Tracing/EventSource.cs:318 
  at Azure.Core.Diagnostics.AzureEventSource.DeduplicateName (System.String eventSourceName) [0x00010] in <0aa90fe0646d47bc95bff520717dbf16>:0 
  at Azure.Core.Diagnostics.AzureEventSource..ctor (System.String eventSourceName) [0x00000] in <0aa90fe0646d47bc95bff520717dbf16>:0 
  at Azure.Core.Diagnostics.AzureCoreEventSource..ctor () [0x00000] in <0aa90fe0646d47bc95bff520717dbf16>:0 
  at Azure.Core.Diagnostics.AzureCoreEventSource..cctor () [0x00000] in <0aa90fe0646d47bc95bff520717dbf16>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Azure.Core.Pipeline.LoggingPolicy..cctor () [0x00000] in <0aa90fe0646d47bc95bff520717dbf16>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineBuilder.Build (Azure.Core.ClientOptions options, Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy[] perCallPolicies, Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy[] perRetryPolicies, Azure.Core.ResponseClassifier responseClassifier) [0x00164] in <0aa90fe0646d47bc95bff520717dbf16>:0 
  at Azure.Identity.CredentialPipeline..ctor (Azure.Identity.TokenCredentialOptions options) [0x00023] in <47110d8b120248e4b903ba2cc44741ea>:0 
  at Azure.Identity.CredentialPipeline.GetInstance (Azure.Identity.TokenCredentialOptions options) [0x00003] in <47110d8b120248e4b903ba2cc44741ea>:0 
  at Azure.Identity.UsernamePasswordCredential..ctor (System.String username, System.String password, System.String tenantId, System.String clientId, Azure.Identity.TokenCredentialOptions options, Azure.Identity.CredentialPipeline pipeline, Azure.Identity.MsalPublicClient client) [0x00069] in <47110d8b120248e4b903ba2cc44741ea>:0 
  at Azure.Identity.UsernamePasswordCredential..ctor (System.String username, System.String password, System.String tenantId, System.String clientId, Azure.Identity.TokenCredentialOptions options) [0x00000] in <47110d8b120248e4b903ba2cc44741ea>:0 
  at MyProject.GraphService.Init (System.String username, System.String password, System.String tenantId, System.String clientId, System.String eventKeyword) [0x00014] in .../MyProject/GraphService.cs:31 
  at MyProject.Features.Auth.AuthViewModel.InnerGetUser () [0x00077] in .../MyProject/Features/Auth/AuthViewModel.cs:57
```

My code is the graphService witch is a standard library v2.1 and it's used by AuthViewModel in the Xamarin.forms project.

```
    public class AuthViewModel: BaseViewModel
    {
    ...
        private async Task InnerGetUser()
        {
            try
            {
                this.IsBusy = true;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Email) ||
                    string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Password))
                    throw new ValidationException("Email e password devono essere compilati");
                
                this._graphService.Init(this.Email, this.Password,
                    this._settingsService.GetStringSetting(Services.Settings.TenantId),
                    this._settingsService.GetStringSetting(Services.Settings.ClientId),
                    this._settingsService.GetStringSetting(Services.Settings.EventKeyword));

                var user = await this._graphService.GetUser();
                this._userService.CurrentUser = new UserDto()
                {
                    Name = user.DisplayName
                };

                this._userService.InvokeOnLoginDone();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                await base.ShowError(e);
            }
            finally
            {
                this.IsBusy = false;
            }
        }
     ...
}

public class GraphService: IGraphService
{
     ...
        public void Init(string username, string password, string tenantId, string clientId, string eventKeyword)
        {
            this._eventKeyword = eventKeyword;
            Console.WriteLine("Creo credentials provider");

            var userNamePasswordCredential = new UsernamePasswordCredential(
                username, password, tenantId, clientId, new TokenCredentialOptions
                {
                    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
                });

            Console.WriteLine("Creo graph service client");

            this._graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(userNamePasswordCredential);
        }
     ...
}
```

Curiously it works fine on a console application in net5.

Nugets:

- Xamarin.forms 5.0.0.2125,
- Azure.Identity 1.4.1,
- Microsoft.Graph 4.6.0

Env:

- mac.os 11.6
- visual studio for mac 8.10.10 (build 8)

sdks:

- .NET 5.0.401,
- Mono 6.12.0.140,
- Xamarin.iOS 15.0.0.6.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your.../MyProject/Features/Auth/AuthViewModel.cs:57 code?

Comment: it calls the piece of code I pasted above, witch tries to instantiate UsernamePasswordCredential and fails. In Xamarin.forms project the caller is authviewmodel.

Comment: I've updated the sample code

Comment: check https://issueexplorer.com/issue/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/24055

Comment: As I can see from the issues 24055, it seems a bug of Azure.Core. A new version will be release soon in October.

Comment: Looks like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating Microsoft.Graph to version 4.7.0 and Azure.Identity to version 1.5.0 has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with Azure.Storage.Blobs getting the exception

`System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Azure.Core.Pipeline.LoggingPolicy' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Azure.Core.Diagnostics.AzureCoreEventSource' threw an exception. ---> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.`

I solved it by installing [Azure.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Core/). I hope it might be useful to you.

Comment: Hi Johan, adding Azure.Core actually prevent the UsernamePasswordCredential to throw, but now the next step (by calling var user = await this._graphClient.Me.Request() .GetAsync();) throws the same exception on another component:

The type initializer for 'Azure.Identity.Azure Identity EventSource' threw an exception. ---> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented. at System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.GetSources ()

Comment: @Gaburiere have you installed both packages on all platforms? Shared, iOS & Android?

Comment: yes, I've tried but with no result. Only by updating Microsoft.Graph to version 4.7.0 and Azure.Identity to version 1.5.0 did the trick! Now there is a problem with keychain access and native linking by adding the custom entitlement to the one that contains the access to keychain itself, but I think this is another story :). It works on android.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this as a Not an answer since I am having the same problem and I tried this without success.
I tried setting all the diagnostic options to false. It did have an effect because it stopped throwing an exception when I created a BlobServiceClient but instead now it throws a System.NotImplementedException when I iterate the results of listing blobs.

```
ClientSecretCredentialOptions options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions();

            options.Diagnostics.IsDistributedTracingEnabled = false;
            options.Diagnostics.IsLoggingContentEnabled = false;
            options.Diagnostics.IsLoggingEnabled = false;
            options.Diagnostics.IsTelemetryEnabled = false;
```

Comment: Hi, i tried to disable diagnostic too, as one of the last post of https://issueexplorer.com/issue/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/24055 says, but with no success.